# unable to open database "/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db" via adb

Tags: adb

Getting error as : unable to open database "/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db": unable to open database file

when i try to change the mobile network via adb using command
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "update global SET value = 1 WHERE name = 'preferred_network_mode'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    copy the /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db 

    to my application folder /data/data/my_app_directory/.

    update the table in the database using the SQLiteDatabase class.

    copy back the database from /data/data/my_app_directory/settings.db 

    to /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/
```

Comment: Thanks Rochi, It's working..
Now i'm getting an error saying sqlite s not found 
error : /system/bin/sh: sqlite3: not found

Please help me in resolving this..

Comment: The sqlite3 binary doesn't get built for the Android OS builds targeting production devices (user build), only the development (eng) builds. You'll have to copy the sqlite3 binary to your device first. http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: i just downloaded sqlite3 from the above link.
Tell me where to copy in the device ??

Comment: i went through that , i did the same way as explained in the web site..
Here my question is where to copy the sqlite3 binary..?
using adb command i have to copy sqlite3 to sdcard( that is the only option)

Please help me out with this ....
Let me know if you are not getting what i'm asking ...

Comment: adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "update global SET value = 1 WHERE name = 'preferred_network_mode'"

to run the above command there was no sqlite3 in my rooted device(As mentioned by you )

now i've to copy the file into device right ..?

Please let me know where and how can run the above command ..

Comment: Thanks Rochi..
Successfully installed the sqlite3 in the device